# Unable to Access /applications API on GitLab.com as Owner - Missing Admin Settings

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

Hello GitLab Community,

I've recently encountered an issue while trying to use the `/applications` API on GitLab.com.
Every time I make a request, I receive a "403-forbidden" error.
Upon further research, I found out that one needs to be an Admin user for the Personal Access Token (PAT) to function correctly with this API.

I logged into my account on gitlab.com(fresh new signin), where my role is set as "Owner".
However, I'm unable to locate the admin settings or the wrench icon that typically represents the Admin Area.

Could someone please guide me on:

1. How to access the Admin Area as an Owner on GitLab.com?
2. Any additional steps or permissions required to successfully use the `/applications` API?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

---

What did I try?
I attempted to access the /applications API on GitLab.com using my Personal Access Token (PAT).

What was I expecting?
I expected to successfully retrieve data from the /applications API since I am designated as the "Owner" of my GitLab account.

What actually resulted?
I consistently received a "403-forbidden" error.
Upon further investigation, I learned that one might need Admin privileges for the PAT to work with this specific API.
However, even though I am an "Owner", I couldn't locate the Admin settings or the wrench icon on GitLab.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only GitLab administrators have access to the admin menu. If the Admin option is not visible to you, it means that you are not designated as a GitLab Administrator

As you said your role is `Owner` which is different than `Admin`.

The Gitlab roles are:

- Guest
- Custom
- Reporter
- Developer
- Maintainer
- Owner

Comment: Yes got it. Admin means the administrator of the instance. 
In GitLab.com that means some subset of GitLab employees. 
You can only reasonably use this on a self-hosted GitLab instance.
The [Applications API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/applications.html) cannot be used to manage group applications or applications of individual users.